# Does generating more random numbers decrease the standard deviation? (In this particular allocation problem)

Tags: random, standard-deviation

Say we want to bake 6 cookies with at least 3 chocolate chips each. We will randomly allocated chocolate chips to each of the 6 cookies until each has at least 3 chocolate chips. The minimum solution will take 18 chocolate chips, but the maximum solution is potentially unbounded. (The average solution is probably a bit above 30.)

If I used dice or a random number generator to try to simulate this problem, will the standard deviation decrease as I generate more 'simulated results'? E.g. 18, 33, 24, etc.

Comment: The standard deviation is scaled such that the sequence of sample standard deviations of a growing sequence of samples is converging to the standard deviation of the distribution. So no. But the standard deviation of sample averages will fall as the samples grow.

Comment: You could read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation The expected standard deviation of a sample rises very slightly with the size of the sample.

Comment: I did a few simulations of this problem and found that the standard deviation tended to fall with a large number of simulations. Was this unexpected?